# Why does the stargate on *Destiny* expel all that steam when the gate shuts down?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe

On Stargate Universe, *Destiny's* gate gushes out a bunch of steam on the bottom of each side of the Stargate. [image: See below]

AFAIK, no other stargates in SG-1/Atlantis series nor the movies does this. I don't think it's due to an older design because the other seeded stargates on that side of the universe don't do this either. Nor do I think it's because it's a ship-based stargate as other such stargates don't do this either.

The steam gushing out happens not only when the 9th chevron is locked in, it also does it when connecting with the local planets when it drops out of FTL.

Sorry for such a dark screenshot, the show is dimly lit throughout the series.

Comment: Not steam, CO2.

Comment: Sorry about the dupe. I searched first but I didn't find anything. I guess I didn't use the right search words.

Comment: No apology necessary. It's not the most obvious set of terms to search for.